# Pins + Vetiver vs MLflow which one to choose for MLOps

Tags: mlflow, tidymodels, mlops, pins, vetiver

I am a big fan boy of `tidymodels` and played around with `vetiver` + `pins` in `R` and `Python` in order to not only develop models but actually deploy them.

However, if you are looking for tools that support in the area of MLOps, sooner or later you will stumble across `MLflow`. Just like `vetiver` + `pins`, `MLflow` helps to track and deploy models and to build a model registry.
I see some pros for `vetiver` like:

- you can directly dockerize a model or create a REST service
- `vetiver`+ `pins` is very, very easy to use and does not require a lot of setup

At this point, I'd like to ask the community if there are any other advantages of `vetiver` + `pins` over `MLflow` or is it advisable to use `MLflow` directly, since it is completely agnostic regarding the programming language and already has a very large community?
Many thanks for your answers! M.

Comment: The integration of MLFlow comes earlier on in your data science processing, with emphasis on experiment tracking/model registries. For things like deploying, it becomes necessary to use CLI. Vetiver comes later in a workflow, so it focuses more on lightweight versioning and being able to quickly deploy models. There is more support in the Python/R API to do things such as make predictions/interacting with your model without using CLI. You could also use a combination of both, it all depends on your use case!